# Find row indices of matches in data.table (can I binary search?)

Tags: r, data.table, binary-search

This seems like such an obvious question but I feel like I am doing it wrong.  I have a vector of strings, and I just want to find the matching row indices in a data.table.  The data.table is keyed by the column I want to match against, so, I think I should be able to use a binary search to find the matching indices.

**Example to follow:**

Here, I have a data.table, keyed by column `c2` and a vector of strings, `new_dat`, for which I would like to find the row indices.

```
library(data.table)

## Example data, a keyed data.table
dat <- data.table(c1=1:10, c2=letters[1:10], key='c2')

## Match at some indices (keyed column so should be binary search?)
new_dat <- c('d', 'j')

## This doesn't feel right -- I don't think this is taking advantage of the
## data.table ordering at all
## Tried some dumb stuff like dat[match(new_dat, c2, 0L), .I]
dat[match(new_dat, c2, 0L), ]  # only want the index of the matches
#    c1 c2
# 1:  4  d
# 2: 10  j

## So, this is the desired result,
## but this is just doing ordinary linear search (I say w/o actually looking at the code)
match(new_dat, dat[['c2']], 0L)
# [1]  4 10
```

#### Edid

I just realized I could do,

```
dat[, ind := 1:.N][match(new_dat, c2, 0L), ind]
```

To get the indices, but still doesn't solve the problem I was trying to portray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to find row indices (while not grouping using the `by` argument) you could specify `which = TRUE` while performing the binary join

```
options(datatable.verbose = TRUE) # Setting to TRUE so we can see the binary join being triggered
dat[new_dat, which = TRUE]
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs <~~ binary join triggered
# [1]  4 10
```

(This will also work without creating `c1` because it doesn't use that column at all)

And, if you just want to perform a normal binary join and see all the values in all the columns, you don't need to use `match` or create an index, just do

```
dat[new_dat]
# Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs <~~ binary join triggered
#    c1 c2
# 1:  4  d
# 2: 10  j
```

In general, as long as your data is keyed (or you using the `on` argument in order to join) **and** `new_dat` is not of class `integer` or `numeric`, `data.table` will automatically trigger the binary join even if `new_dat` is passed to the `i`th argument **without** being wrapped into `.` or `J`. Though, if `new_dat` is one of the above mentioned classes, `data.table` will try to perform a *row indexing* instead. Thus, you will need to use `dat[.(new_dat), which = TRUE]` or `dat[J(new_dat), which = TRUE]` in order to force `bmerge` instead row indexing.